# How to overwrite svg property on Google Charts

Tags: css, google-maps, extjs, svg, treemap

I have implementing Google [TreeMap](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#tree_map)

Since I am using ExtJS Layout and within it is the TreeMap, I had to use iframe, otherwise it would not display anything.

But there is one problem, the Google Map Visualization is defining  random `svg` property.

How to overwrite this random property in my html page and give it a fixed width and height value. Note: I defined fixed width to the charts div, also to the iframe, but nothing is working as svg is overwriting that property.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Pze.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Call document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg") to get all the svg elements then iterate through them and set height and width attributes as necessary.

```
var svgElements = document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
for (var i = 0; i < svgElements.length; i++) {
   var svgElement= svgElements.item(i);
   svgElement.setAttribute("width", "<whatever width you want>");
   svgElement.setAttribute("height", "<whatever height you want>");
}
```